# What is the earliest sedimentation we know of?

Tags: sedimentology

Did large-scale sedimentation occur in any great amount during or soon after the Hadean/Archean period? Or did it only start later, because of the intense geological activity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The oldest known metasedimentary rocks are about 3.8 billion years old, formed in the Eoarchaean era.**

'Metasedimentary' just means they have been metamorphosed, so they started out as sediments. They are found in the [Isua Greenstone Belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isua_Greenstone_Belt) of southwestern Greenland. You can read about their discovery in Moorbath (2009). Quoting from there:

> Published zircon dates strongly suggest that the depositional age of at least part of the [Isua supracrustal belt] could be closer to 3.8 Gyr than to 3.7 Gyr.

According to the International Commission on Stratigraphy (Cohen et al. 2013), this puts them firmly in the [Eoarchaean era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eoarchean).

**References**

Cohen, K, et al. (2013). The ICS International Chronostratigraphic Chart. *Episodes Journal of International Geoscience* **36** (3). [Link to PDF.](http://www.stratigraphy.org/ICSchart/Cohen2013_Episodes.pdf)

Moorbath, S (2009). The discovery of the Earth's oldest rocks. *Notes and Records* **63** (4). [DOI: 10.1098/rsnr.2009.0004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsnr.2009.0004)